# EVO Snap payment gateway using EVO-Snap - PHP HostedPayments library

Tags: php

I want to integrate EVO Payments gateway and I tried EVO-Snap library,

[PHP-HostedPayments](https://github.com/EVO-Snap/PHP-HostedPayments-lib-example)

I can't find the required information mentioned in config-orignal.php file.

```
$cfg = new Config();
$cfg->code = 'merchantprofile'; // Profile Code
$cfg->key = 'key'; // Profile Key
$cfg->environment = false; // Environment - True for Live, False for cert
```

From where I can get that info **code & key** ( I tried with their contact support but they are not replying, that information is also not available any where in the merchant account )

any help would be appreciated, Thank you

Comment: You need to get them directly from EVO I expect by signing up and getting quotes etc etc Whatever their process is for setting up new customers.

Comment: I sent them several emails and still waiting of their reply, Thank you